# Should the $S$-matrix always analytic in coupling constant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, s-matrix-theory, non-perturbative, asymptotics

If we use Dyson series, the $S$-matrix is always an analytic function of the coupling constant. However, if that is the case, how can non-perturbative effects arise in QFT? My question is, should the $S$-matrix always analytic in the coupling constant?

Comment: The Dyson series doesn't converge.

Comment: So S-matrix is not analytic in the coupling constant?

Comment: In general, no. Instanton contributions to the $S$-matrix are generally of the form $\sim e^{-1/g^2}$.

Comment: @Prahar maybe you could elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:** series in QFT are not convergent and have asymptotic behavior, non-perturbative effects cannot be captured from series expansion (all the coefficients are zeros).

**The long answer:**

The answer for your question can be found in original paper by Dyson. Below I sketch some ideas from this paper and refer to related papers.

Consider that one deals with a quantity $F(\alpha)$ which corresponds to "physical observable" of QED (QED is considered for simplicity, "physical observable" can be a scattering cross-section, two-point correlator, etc.), $\alpha=e^2/(4\pi)$. Using perturbation theory, one obtains the following series
$$F(\alpha)=a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+... \tag{*}$$
Next, it is natural to expect that $F(\alpha)$ is an analytic function of $\alpha$ and $(*)$ represents its convergent series representation. If yes, one can change $\alpha\rightarrow-\alpha$ and expects that $F(-\alpha)$ will be an analytic function with convergent series representation. However, in QED this replacement of coupling constant $\alpha$ causes creation of electron (positron) clouds that repel to each other. The main point is that cloud formation is *favorable* (see [Dyson original paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.85.631) for more details). It means that $F(\alpha)$ is not analytic function and its series is not convergent.

How we should understand appeared problem? One possible way is to introduce *Borel image* and *Borel sum*. Consider the function $h(\alpha)$ with series representation,
$$h(\alpha)=\sum_na_n\alpha^n.$$
Next, its Borel image is defined by
$$\bar{h}(z)=\sum_n\frac{a_nz^n}{n!}$$
and if the following integral is well-defined
$$H(\alpha)=\int_0^{\infty}dz\,e^{-z/\alpha}\bar{h}(z),$$
it is called Borel sum of $h(\alpha)$, the function $h(\alpha)$ is called Borel summable.

To develop some intuition about introduced objects, it is useful to consider two functions
$$f(\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\alpha^nn!}{S^n},\quad g(\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^nn!}{S^n}.$$

It is quite easy to see that $\bar{g}(z)$ is well-defined, whereas $G(\alpha)$ is not well-defined: the pole lies in integration contour. Indeed, the Borel image of $g(\alpha)$ is
$$\bar{g}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^nz^n}{S^n}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha z/S},$$
which gives the following expression for the Borel sum,
$$G(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dz\,e^{-z/\alpha}}{1-\alpha z/S},$$
where there is the pole at $z_0 = S/\alpha$. Notice that in case of $f(\alpha)$ everything is ok.
Such effect rises imaginary contribution to $G(\alpha)$,
$$\text{Im}\,G(\alpha)\sim \frac{\pi S}{\alpha}\exp\left(-\frac{S}{\alpha}\right).$$
The key point is that appeared imaginary contribution is non-perturbative with respect to $\alpha$: it cannot be captured by series expansion, all the coefficients are zero.

To conclude, we can write the following correspondence
$$\text{vacuum of theory is stable}\leftrightarrow\text{Borel summable} \\
    \text{vacuum of theory is unstable}\leftrightarrow\text{not Borel summable}$$
and use it as a tool to test theory for non-perturbative effects,
$$\text{theory with coupling $g$}\rightarrow\text{change sign of $g$}\rightarrow\text{Borel summable?}$$
If yes, there is no non-perturbative effects. If no, a theory vacuum is unstable and there are non-perturbative effects.

There are at least two effects that related to above discussion:

1. Fubini instanton in $\lambda\phi^4$ theory (vacuum of theory is unstable with respect to formation of instanton condensate)
2. Schwinger effect in QED (vacuum of theory is unstable with respect to pair production, I am not sure about this!)

For illustration, consider euclidean $\lambda\phi^4$ with $m=0$,
$$\mathcal{Z} = \int\mathcal{D}\phi\exp\left(-\int d^4x\left[\frac{(\partial\phi)^2}{2}+\frac{\lambda\phi^4}{4}\right]\right).$$
To develop perturbative expansions, one should compute coefficients $a_n$. Roughly, it can be done with help steepest descent method. As intermediate step, the classical motion equation should be solved and this solution is called Fubini instanton.

Next, consider change $\lambda\rightarrow -\lambda$. The energy of field configuration is
$$E=\frac{(\partial\phi)^2}{2}-\frac{|\lambda|\phi^4}{4}.$$
This expression is unbounded from below, so instanton production can decrease energy.

More rigorous consideration of mentioned effects and concepts is Lipatov technique and also related to renormalons.

Comment: I think your answer is not really complete/self-contained. (I know it should just sketch the contents of the original paper by Dyson)
Why do you introduce $f(\alpha)$? What is the pole you are mentioning explicitly? How does this relate to the vacuum stability?

Comment: @AlmostClueless , I have tried to update it.